# Why is my iPhone web app not caching and working in offline mode?

Tags: iphone, html, offline

I am trying to make the iPhone cache a HTML5 web application such that I can be offline when I use it. The web application is at www.prism.gatech.edu/~gtg880f and I did not make it. I am borrowing it just to try it out.

There are only 3 files:
index.html
index.js
style.css

I modified the index.html to include `<html manifest="offline2.manifest">`
and `<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />` so that it will look full screen as an offline web app.

My offline2.manifest file are as follow:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
index.js
style.css
debug.js

NETWORK:

CACHE:
```

PS: `debug.js` is from [Jonathan Stark](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/).

When I use firefox, it caches it properly and I was able to use the web app offline. However, it fails in both chrome and safari.

In Chrome, I get the following debug message:

```
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache Error event: Invalid manifest mime type (text/plain) http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~gtg880f/offline2.manifest
```

I googled manifest mime type and it mentions something about `.htaccess` and what not and I am actually not too sure what that means. Following instructions, I went to `etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and change the `ALLOWOVERIDE ALL` from none.

That does not seem to fix anything though and I still get the same error message.

In a nutshell, what I want to be able to do is use my safari browser on iPhone to www.prism.gatech.edu/~gtg880f and save it to my home screen. Then, turn off 3G and wifi and still use the web app.

EDIT: Tried the 1st answer from roryf:
Still does not work. Am I suppose to edit the `httpd.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`? I am using Mac OSX. I added it under this section

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/cache-manifest manifest # added to allow HTML5 offline caching
```

Answer (score 1):

I just checked and it looks like your manifest file is still getting served as text/plain. Here are the steps you can take to fix it.

1. Create a new file called `.htaccess` in the same directory as the manifest file (sometimes the only way to create a file with a name that starts with a dot is to do so on the command line)
2. Edit the file and insert the following line to it:

   ```
   AddType text/cache-manifest manifest
   ```
3. Go to http://web-sniffer.net/ and insert the path to your manifest file to confirm it's being served with the right mime type. It appears the path you need to use here is http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~gtg880f/offline2.manifest

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the file extention to something different.

I had the same problem and when I saved it as cache.manifesto - changed the .htaccess to

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifesto
```

and pointed it in the html files as

```
<html manifest="cache.manifesto" >
```

it wоrked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to achieve to work with my offline storage in mac

Open httpd.conf
Take a backup.
Find "AllowOverride" and change the Value from "None" to "All"

Somewhere close to line # 198

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set the MIME type for .manifest files to `text/cache-manifest` in your Apache config, which is probably what you read about .htaccess (one way to do this).

Adding this to your .htaccess file should work:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest manifest
```

Comment: Check what mime type is being set for that request, will tell you whether your apache config is wrong or the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

My working web app clipping duplicates the filenames in the CACHE: portion of the .manifest file.  Like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
index.js
style.css
debug.js
CACHE:
index.html
index.js
style.css
debug.js
NETWORK:
```

I also included this in a .htaccess file in the same web server directory as the manifest:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest manifest
```

Comment: I did but it still does not work. What is .htaccess file? I can't find it anywhere? Is it the same as httpd.conf? And i have several of httpd.conf. Well, at least 2. One is /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and the other is /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf. I installed XAMPP and ZendServer CE and I seem to have the same files scattered throughout.

Comment: If a .htaccess file doesn't exist, try adding one.

Answer (score 0):

I had same troubles debugging an offline web app on an iPhone as well. The app behaved correctly in Chrome and Safari (both for Windows). A reboot on the iPhone finally did the trick. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could simply make a file called: manifest.php and put this content in it;

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/cache-manifest');
  echo "CACHE MANIFEST\n\n";
  echo "CACHE:\n";

  $hashes = "";
  $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".");
  foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $file) {
    if ($file->IsFile() &&
    $file != "./manifest.php" &&
    substr($file->getFilename(), 0, 1) != ".") {
      echo $file . "\n";
      $hashes .= md5_file($file);
    }
  }

  echo "\n# Hash: " . md5($hashes) . "\n";
?>
```